# How can I detect message boxes popping up in another process?

Tags: c++, winapi

I'd like to execute some code whenever a (any!) message box (as spawned by the [MessageBox Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx)) is shown in another process. I didn't start the process I'm monitoring.

I can think of three approaches:

1. Install a global [CBT Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644977%28VS.85%29.aspx) procedure which tells me whenever a window is created on the desktop. Then, check whether the window belongs to the process I'm monitoring and whether the class name is `#32770` (which is the class name of dialogs according to the [About Window Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633574%28VS.85%29.aspx#system) page at the MSDN). This would probably work, but it would pull the DLL which contains the hook procedure into virtually every process on the desktop, and the hook procedure gets called a lot. It smells like a potential perfomance problem.
2. Try to subclass the `#32770` system window class (is this possible at all?) and look for WM_CREATE messages in my custom window procedure.
3. Intercept the  [MessageBox Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645505%28VS.85%29.aspx) API call (even though the remote process is running already!) and call my code from the hook function.

So far, I only know that the first idea is feasible, but it seems really inefficient. Can anybody think of a simpler solution than that to this problem?

Comment: Try to hook window creation, and check for window class.

Comment: @Pavel: That sounds like what I suggested in the first bullet.

Comment: @nobugz: That's interesting; it's basicaly the CBT hook idae except that - at least from reading the documentation - a WH_SHELL hook isn't called as often (only for toplevel unowned windows). I wonder whether MessageBox() windows always qualify as 'top-level, unowned window'  tho.

Comment: A message box is almost never a top level unowned window. message boxes are owned unless you pass NULL as the HWND parameter.

Comment: Hi Frerich, 

Did you find any solution to this? I have similar use case and looking for the solution. I would appreciate if you can share with us.

Regards
VK

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't think of any efficient solution that doesn't involve injecting code into the other process (this is basically what many types of hooks do by the way).  But if you are willing to go down that path, you *can* intercept calls to MessageBox.

Spend some time stepping through into a call to MessageBox in the debugger in assembly language mode and you'll see that it's an indirect call through a lookup table (that's how exports work). so if you can get your code into the process, you can patch the table to jump to your code instead.

See http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/completeinject.aspx for code showing how to inject a dll into another process.

Answer (score 1):

I think: Approach 2 is impossible. Approaches 1-3 require dll, that is loaded into all processes, and approach 3 is "more right". I suppose searching windows by timer is not suite by some reasons?

Comment: +1: The timer sounds like a plausible approach; I'm just afraid that I can't get the interval right. I'd like to get informed about message boxes as soon as possible, but without putting the system under noticeable load. Still, thanks for pointing that alternative out!

Answer (score 1):

I would go with the first option. You should be able to get away with only installing the hook for the main UI thread of the app you're monitoring,  but if that doesn't work, even global CBT hooks aren't terribly resource intensive in my experience. Of course, you'll want your hook DLL to contain as little as possible other than the hook logic itself. If you need anything bulky, link it dynamically only when you know you're in the right process.

Comment: +1: it's true that installing the CBT hook on just the UI thread of the application would be much cheaper, but unfortunately I don't know which thread is the UI thread. I suppose I could initially install the hook globally and, as soon as I notice that a window was created in my monitored process, determine the thread in which that window lives and install my hook in there instead.